# Divs won't stay using media queries

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a game controller, I am eventually going to use sprites for button presses and so on. At the moment I inlined the photo using image tags.

I then made three empty divs and gave them a size of 50pxx50px and position absolute them over the two buttons and start button.

Using Javascript I made the divs a have a eventlistener  to play sound/start webpage.

My issue now comes to be responsive I used display flex for the webpage, but I believe since I used position absolute it will not be responsive.

I have been trying to use media queries to keep the divs overlaying the buttons on the screen sizes but I still have the issue.

What is the correct/better way to accomplish what I am doing? or why is my media queries failing on page resizing.

A FIDDLE
https://jsfiddle.net/L14xsg7k/

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1name="viewport"/>
<div class="aButton"></div>
<div class="Bbutton"></div>
<div class="Start"></div>

<div id="NES"><img src="images/controllerNES.png" alt="NES- 
Controller"></div>


CSS:
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
.aButton {
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin-top: 21%;
margin-left: 25%;
}
.Bbutton{
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin-top: 21%;
margin-left: 14%;
 }

 .Start{
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: 40px;
margin-top: 22%;
padding-right: 0%;
 }
}
```

Without Media Queries

```
 .aButton{

 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 margin-top: 10%;
 margin-left: 12%;

 }


 .Bbutton{

display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin-top: 10%;
margin-left: 7%;

 }

.Start{

display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: 40px;
margin-top: 11%;
padding-right: 0%;

 }
```

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .aButton {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 21%;
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .Bbutton {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 21%;
    margin-left: 14%;
  }
  .Start {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 22%;
    padding-right: 0%;
  }
}


/*Screen Size Differences */

.aButton {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.Bbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 7%;
}

.Start {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 11%;
  padding-right: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="aButton"></div>
<div class="Bbutton"></div>
<div class="Start"></div>

<div id="NES"><img src="https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.278053540.7309/ap,550x550,16x12,1,transparent,t.png" alt="NES-Controller"></div>
```

Comment: First you need to put your media queries at the end of the code. Because if the selectors are the same it just take the last rules in you file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need media queries for that.
Just put image and buttons in the same container, make the image stretch to container and then place buttons on their coords using position absolute and relative top/left.

```css
#NES {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%
}

.btn {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
}

.aButton, .Bbutton {
    height: 6%;
    width: 4.3%;
}

.aButton {
    left: 78%;
    top: 56.7%;
}
.Bbutton {
    left: 67.3%;
    top: 56.5%;
}

.Start {
  height: 2.75%;
  width: 6%;
  left: 40%;
  top: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div id="NES">
    <img src="https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.278053540.7309/ap,550x550,16x12,1,transparent,t.png" alt="NES-Controller">
    <div class="btn aButton"></div>
    <div class="btn Bbutton"></div>
    <div class="btn Start"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's should work, try below :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width= device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">
 <img src="https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.278053540.7309/ap,550x550,16x12,1,transparent,t.png" alt="">
 <div style="position: absolute; right:19%; top: 57%">A</div>
 <div style="position: absolute; right: 30%; top: 57%">B</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A good answer should be more than "this should work" you should explain what was wrong with the original code and expand on how your code fixes the problem.